# Creating a rating system for randomised groups

Tags: python, random, grouping, rating

So I have this code that groups (1,2,3,4)(x4) into 4 groups, I was trying find a way to rate these groups. E.G. (1,1,1,1) is a good group since there are no other numbers (1,2,3,4) would be the worst group. So does anyone know a way to check the number of different values in a group e.g. (1111) have 1 value, where as (1,2,3,3) has 3 changes.

```
import numpy
import random
members, n_groups = 4, 4
participants=list(range(1,members+1))*n_groups
#print participants 
random.shuffle(participants)

with open('myfile1.txt','w') as tf:
    for i in range(n_groups):
        group = participants[i*members:(i+1)*members]
        for participant in group:
            tf.write(str(participant)+' ')
        tf.write('\n')

with open('myfile1.txt','r') as tf:
    g = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in tf.readlines()]
    print(g)
    print(numpy.mean(g, axis=1))
```

Comment: `len(set(group))` will give you what you want.

Comment: How could I add this into the code?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do. If group is a `Tuple` or `list` then `len(set(group))` will give you the number of unique elements in that `Tuple` or `list`.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify I wanted to count per group how many different number were present, say (1,1,1,1) = 1 as only 1 is presence. Where as (3,2,4,4)=3 as there are 3 numbers present. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, my solution and hence @srattigan 's answer does exactly that.

Comment: @duncster94 not sure what your solution gives me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the above to create a simple function:

For input data of the format (31432123121) you can use:

```
def get_rating(group):
    group = str(group)  # needed to use set 
    return len(set(group))
```

set will sort the number of unique elements into sets

```
>>> set("1111222233")
set(['1', '3', '2'])
>>>
```

then len just gets the length.

For input data like (1,2,3,1,2):

```
def get_rating(group):
    """
    (tuple of ints)->int
    """
    group_str = ""  # create an empty string to rep the nums
    for each_num in group:  # iterate through each of the numbers in the group
        group_str += str(each_num)  # convert each number to a string and append to group_str
    return len(set(group_str))  # return a count of the number of different elements in the input group

print get_rating((4,2,3,4,4,4,1,5))  # simple test for function
```

To use with many lists:

```
# global var
my_groups = [[3, 1, 3, 1], [2, 2, 4, 2], [3, 4, 3, 2], [4, 4, 1, 1]]

def get_rating(group):
    """
    (tuple of ints)->int
    """
    group_str = ""
    for each_num in group:
        group_str += str(each_num)
    return len(set(group_str))

# iterates through each list inside the main list.  
# Note that lists and tuples can be treated the same except when you want 
# to change the internal values
for each_grp in my_groups:  
    print get_rating(each_grp),
```

Remove the comma on the last line of code if you want to print them on separate lines.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify I wanted to count per group how many different number were present, say (1,1,1,1) = 1 as only 1 is presence. Where as (3,2,4,4)=3 as there are 3 numbers present. Does this make sense?

Comment: Done- just have to make sure that you send the data as a tuple to handle any number of ints, or rewrite if you will only have sets of 4 numbers :)

Comment: sorry to ask, just not sure what it does? just trying it getting bit confused! Sorry to be a pain

Comment: just trying it, when I have my list like : [[3, 1, 3, 1], [2, 2, 4, 2], [3, 4, 3, 2], [4, 4, 1, 1]], then put get_rating(group) for this case it gives me 2

Comment: can it rate all off the samples? at the moment it seems just to do the last one

Comment: no problem zoo-ran.  I added comments to the code, but if there is something you'd like me to explain better, please ask.  
If you (for example) wanted to score "more unique" groups with a higher value, this too can be done fairly easily :)

Comment: Yes, updating answer now with new input set

Comment: Thank you so much! Ill have a try with it and get back to you!

Comment: This works really well perfect system I need but instead of having me state the groups the original code makes random groups each time, can your great system do this each time

Comment: This will work for any number of lists of elements within a list, and each list of integers can have any number of elements.  Try it with any number of random combinations and it should work.  If something doesn't work, post it and we'll figure out a solution :) 

If this answers your original question adequately, I'd appreciate if you could mark this as a correct answer- thanks.